How can I prevent implicit conversion with C++ function arguments when using concepts?
I'm trying to use C++20 concepts to enforce an interface on multiple classes (and I do not want to use pure virtual functions).  The problem I'm running into seems to be that implicit conversions allow things that should actually break.
I know about explicit, but it can only be used with ctors and conversion functions.
Let me show some code to illustrate the problem:
#include <concepts>
#include <utility>

// =============================

// Define the interface
template<typename T>
concept ImplementsInterface = requires(T obj, int x)
{
    { obj.func(x) } -> std::same_as<int>;
};


// =============================

// Here is one implementation of the interface
struct B
{
    double func(int x) // Note the INCORRECT 'double' return type
    {
        return x + 5;
    }
};

// This DOES produce a compiler error (yay!)
static_assert(ImplementsInterface<B>);

// =============================

// Here is another implementation of the interface
struct C
{
    int func(char x) // Note the INCORRECT 'char' argument
    {
        return x + 6;
    }
};

// This DOES NOT produce a compiler error (and I want it to!)
static_assert(ImplementsInterface<C>); 

(Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/4sbPhdGhK)
I think C::func(char) uses implicit conversion from char->int and so the compiler does not flag it.  How can I prevent that?  I want an error in the static_assert because of the incorrect argument type in C::func().
Thanks!

Discarding calling conventions: template<typename T> concept ImplementsInterface = requires {    { static_cast<int (T::*)(int)>(&T::func) }; };

Concepts are based on expressions. An expression within a requires expression is valid if that expression can be evaluated and the evaluation results in a type that fulfills the optionally specified concept.
Implicit conversions are a function of expression evaluation. If an implicit conversion is permitted, then it is considered valid as far as the rules of C++ are concerned. So there isn't a simple way to arbitrarily say "don't do implicit conversions in this expression."
But for your cited specific case however, you can fix it:
// Define the interface
template<typename T>
concept ImplementsInterface = requires(T obj, int x)
{
    { obj.func({x}) } -> std::same_as<int>;
};

The use of {x} forces the use of list initialization. Specifically copy-list-initialization. And copy-list-initialization will not allow "narrowing" implicit conversions. The conversion of an int to a char is known to be able to lose information (depending on the value of the int), and this isn't allowed in copy-list-initialization.
But this does not work generally; it only works for known lossy conversions involving fundamental types.

You can try to do something like this:
template <class T>
struct Exact {
    template <std::same_as<T> U>
    operator U() const;
};


template<typename T>
concept ImplementsInterface = requires(T obj, Exact<int> x)
{
    { obj.func(x) } -> std::same_as<int>;
};

Exact<int> is only convertible to int, so this will the case where obj.func takes a char or int64_t or double or ...
But there really isn't a "real" answer to this question. For instance, this still rejects like:
struct X {
    template <std::integral I>
    auto func(I ) -> int;
};

which would otherwise meet the interface just fine.
Ideally it would be possible to accept X but reject the case of just int func(char), but concepts don't really have a provision for that. Maybe you're fine rejecting X. It's basically a question of where exactly you want to draw the line.

Here is another obscure idea: pointers to member functions take a signature...
#include <concepts>
#include <utility>

template <typename T> struct InterfaceChecker
{
    typedef int(T::*Function)(int);

    static auto test(T& obj)
    {
        Function func=&T::func;
        return (obj.*func)(5);
    }
};

template<typename T>
concept ImplementsInterface = requires(T obj)
{
    { InterfaceChecker<T>::test(obj) } -> std::same_as<int>;
};

struct A
{
    int func(char);
    int func(int);
};
static_assert(ImplementsInterface<A>);

struct B
{
    double func(int x) // Note the INCORRECT 'double' return type
    {
        return x + 5;
    }
};
static_assert(ImplementsInterface<B>);

struct C
{
    int func(char x) // Note the INCORRECT 'char' argument
    {
        return x + 6;
    }
};
static_assert(ImplementsInterface<C>);

(Note that I added the A test as well, to have a positive case)
This gives us:
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ -std=c++20 Test.cpp
Test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘static auto InterfaceChecker<T>::test(T&) [with T = B]’:
Test.cpp:18:32:   required from here
Test.cpp:10:23: error: cannot convert ‘double (B::*)(int)’ to ‘InterfaceChecker<B>::Function’ {aka ‘int (B::*)(int)’} in initialization
   10 |         Function func=&T::func;
      |                       ^~~~~~~~
Test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘static auto InterfaceChecker<T>::test(T&) [with T = C]’:
Test.cpp:18:32:   required from here
Test.cpp:10:23: error: cannot convert ‘int (C::*)(char)’ to ‘InterfaceChecker<C>::Function’ {aka ‘int (C::*)(int)’} in initialization

It just doesn't give nice "constraints violated" errors...
